# Changing backgrounds using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change my background when i type in a different city and my code is not working. It only shows the last city. it will not reset and change the background when I type in a different city.  Heres my code.

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#rugby').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    })




    $('#submit-btn').click(function() {
    $("#rugby").get(0).reset();
    var city = $('#city-type').val(); 




     ``if (city == 'New York' || 'NYC' || 'NY') {
     $('body').css('background-image',    'url("../dewaynehw5/images/nyc.jpg")')
}




    if (city == 'San Francisco' || 'SF' || 'Bay Area') {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("../dewaynehw5/images/sf.jpg")')
}




    if (city == 'Los Angeles' || 'LA' || 'LAX') {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("../dewaynehw5/images/la.jpg")')
    }




    if (city == 'Austin' || 'ATX') {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("../dewaynehw5/images/austin.jpg")')
    }





    if (city == 'Sydney' || 'Syd') {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("../dewaynehw5/images/sydney.jpg")')
    }
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Your description goes here">
    <meta name="keywords" content="one, two, three">

    <title>City Background</title>

    <!-- external CSS link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="title">
            <h1>CitiPix</h1>
            <p>Your Cities, Your Pix</p>
        </div>
    </header>
        <div class="container">
            <form id="rugby">
                <input type="text" id="city-type" placeholder="Enter a         city name...">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" id="submit-btn">
            </form>
        </div>
         <script     src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js'></script>
         <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: provide your html code

Comment: Question answered below

Answer (score 0):

I've created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/m7xxkdz6/2/ which should demo the functionality you're wishing to create. I've used CSS background colours rather than images and have used New York and San Francisco as examples.

```
$('#submit').click(function() {

    // Get the input value and set it to lowercase. This way it doesn't matter how the user 
    // enters it into the input box, we'll always be dealing with the same data format
    var inputValue = $('#input').val().toLowerCase();

    // Cache the background element
    var background = $('#background-element');

    // Use a switch statement to match the input value and update the css
    switch (inputValue) {
        case 'new york' :
        case 'nyc' :
            background.css('background-color', 'green');
            break;
        case 'san fsfrancisco' :
        case 'sf' :
            background.css('background-color', 'pink');
            break;
    }  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

simply reset the form at the end of the event .. because you reset the form before it catch a value .. in your code it will catch it empty every time

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#rugby').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

      var city = $.trim($('#city-type').val()); 
      if(){
      }.......


     $("#rugby").get(0).reset(); // <<<< reset here 
     });
});
```

or use it after it catch a value

```
var city = $.trim($('#city-type').val());
$("#rugby").get(0).reset();
```

you can also replace the end of the function with:

```
    city.val('');
```

which will replace the chosen city with an empty string once the function has run.